# how to put NSmutable array into NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i have mutable array named nameArray,ageArray,jobArray i want to put all the 3 arrays into a NSString ,so that i can display all the details in a single cell of UITableView.It should appear like this

name
age
job

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableViewUITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPathNSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //etc....
    cell.textLabel.text = [stringObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I t depends on what elements of you array are. If those are string you can use something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", [nameArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [ageArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row], [jobArray  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: does the size of the cell changes since name,age,job will appear in same cell .

how can i "age" parameter on extreme right side of the cell and job should come below name title .  will this apply to rest of the cells if there multiple number of name , age , job data's automatically